# How do I make this Sequence lazy?

Tags: kotlin, recursion, sequence

I was trying to generate all permutations of a list in Kotlin. There are a zillion examples out there which return a `List<List<T>>`, but my input list breaks those as they try to fit all the results in the output list. So I thought I would try to make a version returning `Sequence<List<T>>`...

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.allPermutations(): Sequence<List<T>> {
    println("Permutations of $this")
    if (isEmpty()) return emptySequence()
    val list = this
    return indices
        .asSequence()
        .flatMap { i ->
            val elem = list[i]
            (list - elem).allPermutations().map { perm -> perm + elem }
        }
}

// Then try to print the first permutation
println((0..15).toList().allPermutations().first())
```

Problem is, Kotlin just seems to give up and asks for the complete contents of one of the nested sequences - so it never (or at least not for a very long time) ends up getting to the first element. (It will probably run out of memory before it gets there.)

I tried the same using `Flow<T>`, with the same outcome.

As far as I can tell, at no point does my code ask it to convert the sequence into a list, but it seems like something internal is doing it to me anyway, so how do I stop that?

Comment: How big is the list, just to check?  Your code looks reasonable, but it's certainly quadratic if not exponential.

Comment: Isn't the list his (0..15).toList() ?

Comment: it doesn't work because there is an error, `if (isEmpty()) return emptySequence()` -> `if (isEmpty()) return sequenceOf(emptyList())`

Comment: @IR42 yep, that was the bug. Facepalm. Of course, this was _completely impossible_ to figure out in the debugger because it kept giving me magic stack frames to line 1 of the file. :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the root cause of your problem, but please note you create new copies of the list with each step: `list - elem`.

Comment: @broot in absence of any better way to do it (e.g. pcollections)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I wish! Permuting a list is O(n!). :)

Comment: Sure, but I meant that `first()` was not exponential but quadratic.

Comment: @LouisWasserman presumably because it removes the first element from the list, so you're paying ArrayList to move all the elements backwards one. Reversing the order could make retrieving the first element faster than that, but ultimately it has to process all elements anyway. I'm also aware of Heap's algorithm which uses one mutable list and a bunch of in-place element swaps, but I'm not so keen on returning mutable lists to the caller. But in any case, that quadratic is quadratic in "moving data around in memory" units, whereas the actual task that has to be run on each will cost much more.

Comment: I would like to ask something, because I am not sure, if I understood the problem for real...

Your "real list" which is not the example List (0..15) here, is so big, that a List of Lists, would break, so a Sequence is robuster and you take N Elements from the Sequence?

Comment: Yeah - I guess that's it... I tested it out with more elements and I got a StackOverflow

Comment: @RaduM if you try to store the result as List then you wouldn't have the memory to store 16! elements and would just get an OOME. If you want to use an even larger number of elements then you'd probably end up using something like the variant of Heap's algorithm which doesn't use the stack.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might consider never even generating a sequence at all. Often, you can get away with taking a callback `(List<T>) => Unit` and simply invoking it on each permutation. If that works for your use case, then your permutation function can simply use the same list and mutate it in-place, rather than generating a bunch of intermediate lists.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I want to map and do other various things after the operation anyway. And I plan to use this for more than one problem, and I am not confident enough to predict what I would need in the future. (And mutating it in-place still isn't safe anyway because the caller could mutate the list also. Unless you provide a read-only view of it to the caller, I guess.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have handled the empty base case incorrectly. You should return a sequence of *one* empty list.

```
// an empty list has a single permutation - "itself"
if (isEmpty()) return sequenceOf(emptyList())
```

If you return an empty sequence, `first` will never find anything - your sequence is always empty - so it will keep evaluating the sequence until it ends, and throw an exception. (Try this with a smaller input like `0..2`!)

Comment: I dunno about the importance of the single-element case. It works without it. Though oddly enough, if I'd considered one element to be a base case, I probably wouldn't have noticed the issue with the empty case.

Comment: @Hakanai Oh wait. Excuse me. I brain-farted.